# How to solve SyntaxError: Unexpected token = after importing a class?

Tags: javascript, class, express, syntax-error

I created a class in a separate JavaScript file and I imported it in another file. However, I get a syntax error in the exported class.

The class shows no errors when it is not exported.

In **Property.js** (the exported class)

```
class Property{

    //constants declarations
    YEAR_AMOUNT = 10;
    PERIOD_AMOUNT = 120;

    //Properties
    closingCosts;
    initialInvestment;

    //arrays declarations
    //income
    adjustedRent= new Array();
    adjustedOtherRevenue = new Array();
    grossRevenue= new Array();
    effectiveRevenue= new Array();

constructor(title, address, askPrice, muniLandEval, muniBuildEval, notes){
 this.title=title;    
    this.address=address;
    this.askPrice=askPrice;
    this.muniLandVal = muniLandEval;
    this.muniBuildVal = muniBuildEval;
    this.notes=notes
}

//other methods
}

export default class Property
```

In **propertyManager.js** (imported into)

```
//handle property (calculations, creation, save)
const express = require('express');
const router  = express.Router();
const Property = require('./Property.js');

router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    //create a Property
    const property = new Property(req.body.title,
        req.body.address,
        req.body.askPrice,
        req.body.muniLandVal,
        req.body.muniBuildVal,
        req.body.notes
    );
})

module.exports = router;
```

The **error** in question

```
D:\ImmoTuul\RE_Analysis_\RE_MVP\server\routes\api\Property.js:4
    YEAR_AMOUNT = 10;
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ImmoTuul\RE_Analysis_\RE_MVP\server\routes\api\propertyManager.js:4:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

I would like to be able to use the class and it's constructor in the **propertyManager** file.

Comment: Try to define your class attributes inside `constructor()` like this: `constructor() {
    this.YEAR_AMOUNT = 10; ...
  }`

Comment: the syntax you are trying to use, i.e. [Field declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations) is not yet implemented, but can be used through a build step like `babel`

Comment: also, you are supposed to use getters and setters, I would recommend you read up on JS classes, https://javascript.info/class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by following @Valijon advice and by using

```
module.exports = Property;
```

Comment: `module.exports` is the commonjs export syntax for nodejs. Not standard ECMA syntax but all pre-processors know what to do with it so should work fine too.

Answer (score 3):

If what you posted is your Property.js file exactly, looks like you have an extra `class` keyword.

`export default class Property;` /// class here in invalid

`export default Property;` //should be this

unless you are exporting and declaring in the same line (which is not what you have shown)